# Linq to SQL not saving to database on SubmitChanges()

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a database with three tables in it. I created all the tables within Visual Studio. My C# code is connecting to the database using Linq to SQL. The table I am having problems with is not updating on SubmitChanges().

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            tbl_Inventoryv2 inv = new tbl_Inventoryv2();
            inv.Title = addTitleTextBox.Text;
            inv.Model = addModelTextBox.Text;
            inv.Category = addCategoryTextBox.Text;
            inv.Quantity = int.Parse(addQuantityTextBox.Text);
            inv.Price = decimal.Parse(addPriceTextBox.Text);
            inv.Description = addDescriptionTextBox.Text;

            db.tbl_Inventoryv2s.InsertOnSubmit(inv);
            db.SubmitChanges();

            int id = inv.IdInventory;

            MessageBox.Show($"Item creation successful. Item number is {id}");
        }
```

My database does have a primary key called IdInventory that is set to increment. Within the program, the correct increments are working as shown in my MessageBox statement above, but it never actually gets saved to the database. I have also checked the properties of the database file in Visual Studio and the path to the database is correct, as well as the Copy to Output Directory is set to Copy if Newer. Most of the questions I have looked up indicate that is usually the problem, but that doesn't look like the case for me. I am new to SQL and interacting with it via Visual Studio/c#, and SQL in general, so any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to use Add instead of InsertOnSubmit, maybe it could help though. After you use db.tbl.add(inv), you should also use db.SaveChanges()

Comment: I tried that right now, but Add is not available. Gives me the red squiggly.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure that all data are being provided? Because you might have some required rows on your table and it might prevent you from saving new data with null values on them.

Comment: Positive. Title, Model, Category, Quantity, Price and Description are the only things in the table, aside from IdInventory. All allow for null except for IdInventory.

Comment: So the MessageBox shows you a newly created Id for your data, right? Do you check if the data was added to your table directly in the Database? I mean by opening Server Explorer and querying your table? Because you shouldn't get an Id of newly created data if it was not saved, you may also be referring to another table, can you provide the code where you *fetch the data from your table to check if it was saved*?

Comment: I'll try to upload it in a bit, but yes, it does get an ID. currently, it will start with 100001 and increment if I try to add multiple entries, but once the program restarts, i goes back to 100001. Also, I have a Windows Form that has a DataGridView box that shows the data in the table before this code, so I would see if anything changed. I also check within Server Explorer and refresh the page to check the table data right after the code I posted, and no change. Might be worth noting that I can add entries from within VS and it will save, just not with my code.

Comment: @Miraziz - It is LInqToSql, not Entity Framework.